# Kernel panic during do-release-upgrade - system in half-upgraded state

Tags: do-release-upgrade

I just upgraded an Ubuntu 18.04 server system to 20.04 via `do-release-upgrade`. Unfortunately, a kernel panic happened during the upgrade. I rebooted and "resumed" the upgrade via `apt upgrade`. Everything seemed to work fine at first. However, after upgrading another server system from 18.04 to 20.04 (no kernel panic this time), I noticed that system 2 has new software installed (such as ModemManager and fwupd) which is missing from system 1.

I assume that `do-release-upgrade` was supposed to install these new packages. So I wonder if there is a way to complete the upgrade so that system 1 will be in the state it was intended to be in.

Comment: Hello. If you want a stable system do a complete new install of 20.04 on the one that crashed. Of course you did a complete backup of all important files before you started the version upgrade.

Comment: You may find this link on kernel panic interesting. http://thexlab.com/faqs/kernelpanics.html